# htmlのテキスト情報だけ、Sublime Textでコピーしたい

Tags: html, sublimetext

下記のように、なっているhtmlのテキスト情報だけ、Sublime Textでコピーしたいです。
brがなければ、可能なのですが、brを付けると、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>を使ってもここで引っかかってしまいます。

```
<p>・開始</p>
<p>・開始</p>
<p>・開始</p>

<p>・開始<br>改行後の文章</p>
<p>・開始<br>改行後の文章</p>
<p>・開始<br>改行後の文章</p>
```

正規表現で、pの中をすべて選択することが恐らく可能ですが、今度は関係ない所の情報までコピーされてしまいます。
何とかできないでしょうか？

これはブログ用なのですが、ツイッターや音声化して動画としても再利用したいです。

中身のテキストだけ切り抜けないでしょうか？

ブラウザ上で表記してからコピペするとある程度は、可能そうですね。
タグだけ取り除いてくれるウェブサービスがあればこれでもいいです。

最後に、
1
2
3
4。

1
2
3
4。
と続いているテキストの1行目だけを選択したい場合は、手動で行うしかないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

使用環境とか、入力はどこから取ってきて、出力はどのようになれば良いのか、
あるいは何かのソフトやサービスの一部に組み込むのか、といったことが補足
されると、回答が付きやすいでしょう。

単体のツールならば、Windows用にこんなのが見つかります。
[HTML→テキスト変換ツール H2Tconv](http://nekomimi.la.coocan.jp/freesoft/h2tconv.htm) C++ Builder用ソースコードも入っています。
[HTMLテキスト抽出ツール「WebTextClip」](http://www.bzwind.com/~ntak/wtc2.html)

Web上のサービスだとこれとか。
[WebサイトのHTMLテキスト取得](https://tool-taro.com/wget/)
追記
[鬼ツールズ HTMLタグの削除](http://www.oni-tools.com/tools/strip_html_tags)
[クロクロ・ツールズ HTMLタグ除去](https://crocro.com/tools/item/del_html_tag.html)
[NAVERまとめ ウェブ・ページのHTMLタグを消して、テキストだけを簡単に取り出せるサイト](https://matome.naver.jp/odai/2144538929295736501)

あとはスクレイピングという技術を組み込んで、自分でWebサービスのサイトを作る等ですか。

Comment: オニツールで確かに削除できました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 最後の、四行続いているテキストの一行目だけを選択するという事は出来ないのでしょうか？いろいろと恐縮です。

Comment: Sublime Text側で、そうしたマクロやプラグインを作ってみてはどうでしょう？ Unix系の `head` コマンドを呼び出して結果を受け取るとか。macなら元から入っているでしょうし、WindowsでもMinGWとかWSLで入れられるのでは？

Comment: そこまでしないと出来ないのですね。ありがとうございました。